# Mobile data keeps switching off

Tags: ios, cellular-data

I am on a iPhone 5s with iOS 12.4.8. The problem I am facing, if I go to Settings > Mobile Data >  and then switch the toggles for apps such as Google Maps to enable mobile data, next time I am checking there, the toggles are switched off again.

Is anyone else facing a similar problem?

Comment: This seems to be some sort of glitch, have you tried restaring your iPhone?

Comment: Yes and unfortunately it didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by resetting the settings.